# How to apply Autofill function for a dynamic range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the process of creating a macro that should return 3 results:

- adds 3 columns to the right after column C
- implements characters per line counting formula which returns number of characters per line from column C in newely created column D
- implements total characters count formula in column E (counts sum of characters count returned from column D)

**Future Result**: As current code gives formula results in cells D2 and E2 I want it to run Autofill function so that no matter the number of rows in the spreadsheet it gives results for all of them (just like double-clicking in the bottom right corner of a cell with formula).

This is how code looks like now:

```
Sub AutoFillTest

Columns("D:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove '

     Range("D2").Select
     ActiveCell.Formula = "=Len(Left(C2, IfError(Find(Chr(10), C2, 1), 99))) & IfError("" ,"" & 
     Len(Mid(C2, Find(Chr(10), A2, 1) + 1, 99)), """")"
     #Here goes Autofill part which I'm looking for#

     Range("D2,E2").Select
     Range("E2").Activate
     ActiveCell.Formula = "Len("C2")"
     #Here goes Autofill part which I'm looking for#
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use autofill [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill):

```
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")

SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

Then what you would need to is find the last row for the columns you need.

UPDATE

With your need for dynamic last row, something simple like this might work:

Add a function:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(str_TabName As String, lng_Column As Long, lng_Row As Long) As Long
 
Sheets(str_TabName).Select
'Range(str_Column & lng_Row).Select
Cells(lng_Row, lng_Column).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
 
GetLastRow = ActiveCell.Row
 
End Function
```

Then amend the code like this:

```
Sub AutoFillTest
    
'' Get last row
Dim lng_LastRow as Long
'' Pass argument as required sheet, the column as a number, and the last row to start from
lng_LastRow = GetLastRow("Sheet1", 4, 100000)

    Columns("D:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove '
    
         Range("D2").Select
         ActiveCell.Formula = "=Len(Left(C2, IfError(Find(Chr(10), C2, 1), 99))) & IfError("" ,"" & 
         Len(Mid(C2, Find(Chr(10), A2, 1) + 1, 99)), """")"
         #Here goes Autofill part which I'm looking for#
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D2")
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D" & lng_LastRow )
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
    
         Range("D2,E2").Select
         Range("E2").Activate
         ActiveCell.Formula = "Len("C2")"
         #Here goes Autofill part which I'm looking for#
```

'' apply from the example above and see if it works for you
End Sub

Note I haven't checked your formulae

Comment: Thanks, so in this case I should add what you pasted below ActiveCell.Formula something:
`code

     Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2")
     Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D20")

SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
code`

Comment: yes. What's the logic on how you will determine last row? ie, How do you know D20 is the range you want to be populated as a constant? Or will it be dynamic?

Comment: This is also a part of my question - I would like autofill to go as far as there is something in the column to the left - just like "manual" autofill. I havent't figured it out yet. 
I'm not sure what's wrong but when I try the code I pasted in the previous comment I get a response "AutoFill" method of range failed" but I thought that in SourceRange showiung only the cell with formula will be enough.

Comment: I have updated the code to give an example of how to dynamically get last row